# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: .ebextensions for a specific Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two Environments at `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`: `Development` and `Production`.

I would like that `.ebextensions/app.config` only run on `Production` environment.
Theres any way to do that?

---

app.config:

```
container_commands:
  01-command:
    command: "crontab .ebextensions/cronjob"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: Here are some similar/related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42821299), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28425360), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42535753) (just to link them all together)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to `TNICHOLS` idea I found a solution:

---

Change the environment `PARAM1` variable value to `MyAppEnv-Production` (or what you want).

app.config:

```
container_commands:
  command-01:
    command: "/bin/bash .ebextensions/crontab.sh"
    leader_only: true
```

crontab.sh:

```
if [ "$PARAM1" == "MyAppEnv-Production" ]; then
  crontab -l > /tmp/cronjob

  #CRONJOB RULES
  echo "00 00 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://localhost/cronexecute > /dev/null 2>&1" >> /tmp/cronjob

  crontab /tmp/cronjob
  rm /tmp/cronjob
  echo 'Script successful executed, crontab updated.'
else
  echo 'This script is only executed in the production environment.'
fi
```

Comment: AWS added a 'test' option to container commands, so the if statement from crontab.sh can be moved into app.config after leader_only: `test: '[ "$PARAM1" == "MyAppEnv-Production" ]'`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a simple way to do it in the way you're thinking. You could have the config file run and execute a second script (perhaps cron.sh). Inside cron.sh you can check the environment name and then add the cronjobs accordingly. Haven't tested it, but I think that should work.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get the running `Environment Name` in .sh script?

Comment: Check my solution based in your idea ;) Thanks!