# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: How to use environment variables in ebextensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

We are trying to store environment specific application configuration files in s3. 
The files are stored in different subdirectories which are named after the environment and also have the environment as part of the file name.

Examples are

```
dev/application-dev.properties
stg/application-stg.properties
prd/application-prd.properties
```

The Elastic Beanstalk environments are named **dev, stg, prd** and alternatively I also have an environment variable defined in Elastic Beanstalk named ENVIRONMENT which can be **dev, stg or prd**.

My question now is, how do I reference the environment name or ENVIRONMENT variable when downloading the configuration file from a config file in .ebextensions?

I tried using a `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }` reference in .ebextensions/myapp.config but get a syntax error when deploying.

The content of .ebextensions/myapp.config is:

```
files:
  /config/application-`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`.properties:
    mode: "000666"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.mycompany.mybucket/`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`/application-`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`.properties 
    authentication: S3Access

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
          type: S3
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          buckets: com.mycompany.api.config
```

The error I get is:

```
The configuration file .ebextensions/myapp.config in application version
manualtest-18 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: 
mapping values are not allowed here in "<reader>", line 6, column 85: 
... .config/stg/application-`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`.prop ... ^ , 
JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (f) at position 0.. 
Update the configuration file.
```

What is the correct way of referencing an environment variable in a .ebextensions config file in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled to get this working, until I discovered that the Sub function doesn't appear to be available in ebextensions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html

This means that you need to fall back to `Fn::Join` and `Ref`, at least until support for `Sub` is introduced to ebextensions. It also seems that the files attribute requires a fixed path (and I couldn't use `Fn::Join` in this context).

My overall solution to this was as follows:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: S3
          buckets: arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-xxx
          roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

files:
  "/tmp/application.properties" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["https://s3-xxx.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-xxx/path/to/application-", { "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, ".properties" ]]}
    authentication: S3Auth

container_commands:
  01-apply-configuration:
    command: mkdir -p config && mv /tmp/application.properties config
```

This will result in an `application.properties` file (without the environment name qualifier) in a `config` directory next to the deployed application instance.

If you want to keep the name of the environment as part of the file name using this approach, you will need to adjust the command that moves the file to use another `Fn::Join` expression to control the filename.

Answer (score 10):

Your `.ebextensions` config file was almost correct. Substituting the file name with environment variable or AWS resource name won't work, for that do as in Mark's answer to rename the file created in `container_commands` section.

The `source` option value trying to access AWS resource name using [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-ref) was correct, it just had to be surrounded by single quote `'`, like below:

```
files:
  /config/application.properties:
    mode: "000666"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.mycompany.mybucket/`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`/application-`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`.properties'
   authentication: S3Access
```

And to access environment variables use [Fn::GetOptionSetting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-getoptionsetting). Environment variables are in `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment` [namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html).

Below example access an environment variable `ENVIRONMENT` in `source` option of `files`:

```
files:
  "/tmp/application.properties" :
    mode: "000666"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.mycompany.mybucket/`{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`/application-`{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "OptionName": "ENVIRONMENT ", "DefaultValue": "dev"}}`.properties'
    authentication: S3Auth
```

Comment: this is not correct this gives Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AWS_ENVIRONMENT] in the Resources block of the template

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there .ebextensions are using YAML format, while your trying to use JSON. Use `Ref: AWSEBEnvironmentName`.
In addition, you can take advantage of `Sub` function to avoid pesky `Join`:

`!Sub "/config/application-${AWSEBEnvironmentName}.properties"`